# Свой SQL Server или parser query(?)

Tags: c#, odbc, sql-server, sql

Нужно реализовать что-то вроде мини sql сервера, но к нему нужно подключаться через SQL Server Management Studio. Т.е. чел подключается через SSMS к удаленному серверу, где нет MSSQL Server, но есть мой парсер запросов, который обрабатывает данные и выплевывает ResultList.

Обработчик будет поддерживать только обычный SELECT, где макс. 4 поля и несколько параметров для условий.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать? Смотрел в сторону ODBC, но (как я понял) он только может коннектиться к серверам БД.

Comment: ODBC нужен для того, чтобы с вашим сервером могли общаться другие.

Comment: @maxleo, т.е. можно написать odbc прослойку + мой обработчик, которая будет обрабатывать запросы и выплевывать результат?

Comment: @NameX, именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего писать не нужно, все уже написано :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572417/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusforplusCreatingpl
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668796%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Имеется возможность прикрутить все это дело, к контексту Entity Framework

Comment: Нет, Вы меня не поняли. Мне нужно написать что-то вроде Источника данных, только источник данных это мой модуль, который берет данные с оборудования.

Comment: @NameX, если я правильно понял, вам предлагают писать не ODBC интерфейс, а OData интерфейс. Не лишнего смысла, но сложнее.